# Call another action after API call is successful in redux?

Tags: reactjs, api, redux

I am doing a POST request to an API endpoint that's supposed to change the boolean value of a property to 'true'.

So roughly:

```
export const toggleToTrue = payload => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        let store = getState();         
        dispatch({ type: "TOGGLE_TO_TRUE", payload });
        return axios
            .post(
                someendpoint,
                { payload },
                {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
                        "Content-type": "application/json"
                    }
                }
            )
            .then(res =>
                dispatch({
                    type: "TOGGLE_TO_TRUE_RESOLVE",
                    res: res.data
                })
            )
            .catch(err =>
                dispatch({
                    type: "TOGGLE_TO_TRUE_ERROR",
                    err: err
                })
            );
    };
};
```

Then on my reducer:

```
case "TOGGLE_TO_TRUE":
    newState.status = action.type;
    newState.error = null;
    return [...state, newState];
    break;
case "TOGGLE_TO_TRUE_RESOLVE":
    if (action.res.errorCode == 0) {
        newState.status = "TOGGLE_TO_TRUE_SUCCESS";
        // Need to dispatch again the action to get updated list
    } else {
        newState.status = "TOGGLE_TO_TRUE_ERROR";
        newState.error = getErrorMessage(action.res);
    }
    return [...state, newState];
    break;
case "TOGGLE_TO_TRUE_ERROR":
    newState.status = action.type;
    newState.error = getErrorMessage(action.err);
    return [...state, newState];
    break;
```

Currently, my POST request is successful however, since I don't get data back from this post request, I need to do another GET request to get the updated object.

Where do I do it in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Right after dispatching the `TOGGLE_TO_TRUE_RESOLVE` action:

```
...
.then(res =>
  dispatch({
    type: "TOGGLE_TO_TRUE_RESOLVE",
    res: res.data
  })
)
.then(callTheApiAgain)
.then(res =>
  dispatch({
    type: "TOGGLE_TO_TRUE_SUCCESS",
    res: res.data
  })
);
```

But you also need to handle the new action `TOGGLE_TO_TRUE_SUCCESS` in your reducer.

Comment: As in I need to do .then(getAPI())..? With getAPI being an action creator like toggleToTrue in my example above?

Comment: Yes, exactly like above.